# Нужно дописать в коде среднее арифметическое заданого вектора

Tags: c, массивы

Вот само задание:
**Ввести вектор действительных чисел. Все элементы вектора, размещены перед его
минимальным элементом, уменьшить на половину от среднего арифметического элементов
введенного вектора.**

Вот код,который я написал,сказали сделать это задание через среднее арифметическое чисел внутри вектора,но я не пойму как это сделать:

````
#define N 100

int main()
{
   int n;
   printf("enter the amount of elements of your vector: ");
   scanf_s("%d", &n);
   double vect[N];

   printf("enter your vector: ");
   for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
   {
       scanf_s("%lf", vect + i);
   }

   int min = vect[0], nmin = 0;

   for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
   {
       if (min > vect[i])
       {
           min = vect[i];
           nmin = i;
       }
   }
   printf("min=%d, nmin=%d\n", min, nmin + 1);
   for (int i = nmin + 1; i < n; ++i)
   {
      
       vect[i] = vect[i] / 2; //вот тут я поделил на 2,а нужно среднее арифметическое введенных цифр
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
   {
       printf("%.2lf ", vect[i]);
   }
   return 0;
} ```

Буду благодарен за помощь!
````

Comment: "введенных цифр вектора"? Точно? Именно цифр? Не содержащихся в векторе чисел?

Comment: @Harry Введеных в вектор чисел, не правильно выразился

Comment: Ну так вводя числа в вектор, набирайте заодно их сумму, а потом поделите на количество...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double vect[N], avg = 0;

printf("enter your vector: ");
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    scanf_s("%lf", vect + i);
    avg += vect[i];
}

avg /= n;   

int min = vect[0], nmin = 0;

 ....

 vect[i] = vect[i] / (avg/2);
```

Comment: выдает неправильный ответ...

Comment: Ну, сами разберитесь, что значит **"уменьшить на половину"**. Может, надо не делить, а вычитать... После "среднего всех цифр" я могу поверить в любой вариант :)

Comment: все я правильно делал, уважаемый.Проблема была в самом коде,но я уже все исправил.Все равно спасибо за помощь